# Unitary diagonalization of a normal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

I will gladly appreciate explanation on how to do so on this matrix:

$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        i & 0 \\
        0 & i \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

I got as far as calculating the eigenvalues and came up with $λ = i$.
when trying to find the eigenvectors I came up with the $0$ matrix.

what am I doing wrong?

Much appreciation and thanks in advance.

Comment: You are correct about the eigenvalues.  The eigenspace is everything, so any basis will work.

Comment: It's hard to tell what you're doing wrong wish this little detail. Please provide the eigenvectors' computations.

Comment: So vasically choosing the trivial base. (1,0) , (0,1) will suit the eigenvectors as they are already normalized

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A=\begin{pmatrix}{i}&{0}\\{0}&{i}\end{pmatrix}$, then $I_2^*AI_2=A=D\text{ (diagonal)}$ and $I_2=\begin{pmatrix}{1}&{0}\\{0}&{1}\end{pmatrix}$ is an unitary matrix.

Answer (score 1):

You got zero matrix that means every vector is in the eigenspace of $i$. So choose any two linearly independent vector and that will be your basis. Also its already diagonal so standard basis are the eigenvectors(if the matrix is with respect to standard basis).

Answer (score 1):

Since $Ov=O$ is satisfied for all non-zero vectors $v$ so take any two arbitrary but linearly independent of them like $\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\end{pmatrix}$.